# What factors were used for determining leap years while the Israelites were in the desert?

Tags: halacha, calendar

I am trying to "co-ordinate" Rambam"s explanation of how to determine Judaic leap years with a key verse in the Torah.

Ranbam states in Mishneh Torah, Sanctification of the New Month 4:2:

Mishneh Torah, Sanctification of the New Month 4:2-3:

> על שלשה סימנין מעברין את השנה. על התקופה ועל האביב ועל פירות האילן.
>   כיצד בית דין מחשבין ויודעין אם תהיה תקופת ניסן בששה עשר בניסן או אחר
>   זמן זה מעברין אותה השנה. ויעשו אותו ניסן אדר שני כדי שיהיה הפסח בזמן
>   האביב. ועל סימן זה סומכין ומעברין ואין חוששין לסימן אחר. וכן אם ראו
>   בית דין שעדיין לא הגיע האביב אלא עדיין אפל הוא. ולא צמחו פירות האילן
>   שדרכן לצמוח בזמן הפסח. סומכין על שני סימנין אלו ומעברין את השנה. ואף
>   על פי שהתקופה קודם לששה עשר בניסן הרי הן מעברין. כדי שיהיה האביב מצוי
>   להקריב ממנו עומר התנופה בששה עשר בניסן. וכדי שיהיו הפירות צומחין כדרך
>   כל זמן האביב.

Sefaria.org translation (except for italics, my corrections based on DoubleAA's & user6591 help in comments):

> For three indicators we make the year a leap [year]. For the epoch and
>   for the spring and for the fruit of the trees. How? The court
>   calculates and knows; if the epoch of Nissan (when the sun enters
>   Aries) will be on the 16th of Nissan or after this time, they make the
>   year into a leap [year]. And they make that Nissan an Adar Sheini in
>   order that the Passover will be in the spring time. And on this
>   indicator, we rely and make leap [years] and we are not concerned
>   about another indicator.  And similarly, if the court saw that the
>   spring has yet to arrive, rather the fruit *is still "hiding*". And the fruit of
>   the trees that tend to sprout around Passover have not sprouted. We
>   rely on these two indicators and make the year a leap [year]. So that
>   the spring will be present to offer up from it the waved omer (an
>   offering of grain) on the 16th of Nissan. And in order that the fruit
>   will sprout normally throughout the spring time.

Deuteronomy 16:1:

> שָׁמוֹר֙ אֶת־חֹ֣דֶשׁ הָאָבִ֔יב וְעָשִׂ֣יתָ פֶּ֔סַח לַיהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ
>   כִּ֞י בְּחֹ֣דֶשׁ הָֽאָבִ֗יב הוֹצִ֨יאֲךָ֜ יְהוָ֧ה אֱלֹהֶ֛יךָ
>   מִמִּצְרַ֖יִם
>   לָֽיְלָה׃
>
> Observe the month of Abib, and keep the passover unto the LORD thy
>   God; for in the month of Abib the LORD thy God brought thee forth out
>   of Egypt by night.

Most translations of the word "Aviv" that I have seen translate this as "Spring", which would tie this to the Solar equinox, only.

However, Rashi on Deuteronomy 16:1:1: (excerpt)

> **שמור את חדש האביב.** , שיהא ראוי לאביב להקריב בו את מנחת העמר,
>   ואם לאו, עבר את השנה:

That the month should be one that is appropriate for the (barley) ripening in order to sacrifice the Omer sacrifice. If it is not this way, then, make a leap year.

My question - Rash"i seems to translate "Aviv" as "ripening" and tie this to an agricultural event. Also, the Omer offering was done only in the land of Israel (See Vayikra 23:10.)

Also, in the desert there were no trees, and there was no rainy season either.

So, when the Torah refers to "The Month of Aviv", does that mean "Spring" based on the equinox? If so, can we safely assume that this was the only reason to have a leap year while they were in the desert for 40 years? How was this calculated (I.e. - who knew "Sod Ha'ibur" ("Secrets of intercalation") and who made this decision?

Comment: 'Aviv' means something like 'ripening [grain]' and was later used to refer to the time when that happens. (Just like in English 'fall' became the term for the time leaves do that.) Consider its usage in Exodus 9:31 and Leviticus 2:14

Comment: Incidentally, whose translation of the Rambam is that? They seem to have mistranslated אפל possibly leading to your confusion . It derives from אפילות (Exo 9:32) not אפלה (Exo 10:22) though its possible those words are etymologically related.

Comment: @DoubleAA Re 1st comment - I do know that there are 2 meanings. I am just uncertain as to how to coincide it with what Rash"i explains, and then Ramba"m adds a purely calendrical factor in addition to an agricultural one. Re 2nd comment - this is from Sefaria. Can you define the 2 words in your comment. I'm not yet understanding the distinction, so that I can edit my question.

Comment: @DanF Double means to say they should have translated the word as late, as in late blooming, not dark.

Comment: @user6591 I missed that. Thanks for the help. I edited. Feel free to edit further, if needed.